# How to display folder names on html page using java script?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to list the files in a directory using only javascript? To clarify, I mean list the files on the server, not the files on the clients computer. For instance:

www.domain.com/files/

contains 4 images (.jpg)

Comment: for now displaying files on any local directory can do .

Comment: Nope. You need PHP or any server side language

Comment: You could serve the directory as `JSON`, parse `JSON` at client-side. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script/

Comment: Answer is yes if your server reponse your request with such information .

Comment: Are you trying to read directories at local filesystem?

Comment: @Yogesh You can use `<input type="file">` element with `webkitdirectory allowdirs` attributes, `change`, `drop` events to select and drop a directory. Use `.getFilesAndDirectories()` at firefox, `.webkitGetAsEntry()`, `.createReader()` `.readEntries()` at chrome, chromium. At firefox `drop` event does not list selection as a `Directory`, but a `File`. At directories containing both files and directories, directories are read first. It is not possible to determine how many directories will be selected, use recursion,  `Promise` to perform tasks when all directories and files have been read.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for:

```
fs.readdirSync("./")
```

For example, in Express:

```
router.get("/someFiles", function(){
    return "<ul>"
        + fs.readdirSync("/path/to/someFiles")
            .map(function(fName){
                return "<li>"+fName+"</li>";
            })
        +"</ul>"
    ;
});
```

What I understand you are searching for:

- [Express Serve-Index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index)

Comment: No .I just want to display names of all folder present in my C drive

Comment: @Yogesh _"To clarify, I mean list the files on the server, not the files on the clients computer."_ , _"No .I just want to display names of all folder present in my C drive"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to get the local directories of the client for obvious security reasons. If you want to receive a file, then use a file input field.

Neither is possible to get the server files natively, because JavaScript is a client side language.