# JQuery-FIle-Upload plugin works when I link to online JS and CSS files but not when I link to offline versions of same files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

**PROBLEM:**

The [JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin works fine when I open its `basic-plus.html` file in the browser, but it links to a few `.css` and `.js` files on the internet in the `href` and `src` attributes of its `style` and `script` tags.

**After I downloaded those files from the internet and linked to their local versions in `basic-plus.html`, I get
`File Upload Failed`
when I try to upload a file.**

The question is why and how do I fix this?

**EXPLANATION:**

I am trying to use the JQuery-File-Upload plugin. I followed [their setup guide](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup) and it worked. That is I downloaded the .zip repository from their Github and extracted it in my LAMPP's `htdocs` folder. Then I opened `basic-plus.html` in browser and it worked perfectly fine.

[image]

The thing is that the `basic-plus.html` has the following statements:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>

<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**That is, this `.html` page is including `.css` and `.js` files from the internet.**

My requirement is to make a webpage (which contains a PHP file uploader) which works offline.

So I opened in the browser the links given in the values of `href` and `src` attributes of the `<link>` and `<script>` elements above, and **I downloaded those `.css` and `.js` files into my project folder, and changed the paths in the values of `href` and `src` attributes to local paths where I placed the files:**

```
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
...

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>

<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Now when I open `basic-plus.html` in the browser, I get `File Upload Failed` when I try to upload a file.**

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make your code works with `file:///` local protocol ?

Comment: @MamdouhFreelance I mean I need my code to work without an internet connection.

Comment: @Sie Are any errors logged at `console`?

Comment: @guest271314 yeh thanks

Comment: @Sie how "without an internet connection" ? so where you will upload your file ? you cant make ajax call to upload from `file:`  protocol to `http(s):` remote server, thats cross origin issue.

Comment: @Sie See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script/