# Print file via Raw Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

look ...

i have a server installed on a linux machine ( RHEL 7 + PHP ) . where i have a server called " Printer " acessible by : 192.168.0.48/Printer.

i have a page php at my server that create a file with some ZPL LANGUAGE inside on this location

' \Printer\documents\'

its possible to send the file that has been generated to the printers of side-client via " window.open() " ?

or for example , get the content of this file and insert of this function ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function printZpl(zpl) {
   var printWindow = window.open();
   printWindow.document.open('text/plain')
   printWindow.document.write(zpl);
   printWindow.document.close();
   printWindow.focus();
   printWindow.print();
   printWindow.close();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the result of code at Question?

Comment: show me a window with ZPL LANGUAGE , but i wanna populate this windows from a file , not from "write ".

Comment: What is "ZPL LANGUAGE"?

Comment: This is a ZPL language , that must be send to the printer.
^XA        
^FXTest ZPL^FS
^FO50,100
^A0N,89^FDHello ZPL^FS
^XZ

Comment: You can request the file using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` and set `document.body` `.textContent` of opened `window` property to `.responseText` or result of `.text()`, then call  `print()`

Comment: could u make a example ? to me undestand better.

Comment: _"could u make a example ? to me undestand better."_ See post

Answer (score 0):

You can pass string to `encodeURIComponent()` at function call and set string as `.textContent` of `<pre>` element at opened `window` to preserve new line characters for at `print()` call

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="print">Print file</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function printZpl(zpl) {
      var printWindow = window.open(`data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><pre>${zpl}</pre><script>print();<\/script></body></html>`);
      printWindow.focus();
    }

    var zpl = `^XA 
^FXTest ZPL
^FS 
^FO50,100 
^A0N,89
^FDHello ZPL
^FS 
^XZ`;
document.getElementById("print")
.onclick = function() {
  printZpl(encodeURIComponent(zpl))
};
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/TBx0tNP0WkDODAz71qzO?p=preview

Comment: but , how could get content from a file ? without need write the zpl lan guage. example , the zpl must be from a file "sample.txt".

Comment: @Kamikaz0r You can use `<input type="file">` to upload local file and `FileReader`, `FileReader.readAsText()` to read file, or `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to request a remote file, see [How to print all the txt files inside a folder using java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script/)